# Are there English dialects that still use the verb "to snithe"?

Tags: word-usage, dialects

Wiktionary says that [it's used in some dialects in Northern England](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/snithe#English), but I wonder if that information is still up-to-date. Have you personally heard the verb being used?

Comment: [Here's](https://books.google.com/books?id=cHgkCwAAQBAJ&pg=PT170&lpg=PT170&dq="snithe+wind") an example of "a snithe wind".

Comment: Doesn't that answer your own question?  Yes. In Northern England there exist dialects that use it ....

Comment: AFAIK this word has not made its way across the sea to Ireland.

Comment: @DavidM The OP is asking if anyone can verify that Wiktionary is correct that it is current in dialect, so a link to wiktionary doesn't answer that.

Comment: @Laurel That book is set in 1819 so doesn't provide evidence of current usage.

Comment: Doesn't plot on an ngram.